# Transform Array

Tags: php, arrays

How do I get this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [max] => 5
            [year] => 2007
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [max] => 6.05
            [year] => 2008
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [max] => 7
            [year] => 2009
        )

)
```

Into this format:

```
[year] => [max]
```

(ashamed at my ignorance...one of those days)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$result = array();
foreach($array as $v) {
    $result[$v['year']] = $v['max'];
}
```

There you go.

Answer (score 1):

you would need to iterate through your current array and put the data into a new array.

```
$result = array();
foreach($currenArray as $x) 
{
    $result[$x['year']] = $x['max'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way?

```
$dest = array();
foreach ($src as $k => $v) {
  $dest[$v['year']] = $v['max'];
}
```